Wkhtmltopdf Content extends to Footer
I want the content dynamically extend to footer. The footer-spacing is currently not working for me.
Output printout:

This is my controller:
            $pdf = PDF::loadView('view-purchase-order/po-form-print/poContent', compact('poData'));

            $pdf->setOptions([
                'margin-top' => 100,
                'margin-right' => 10,
                'margin-bottom' => 10,
                'margin-left' => 10,
                'page-size' => 'legal',
                'header-html' => view('view-purchase-order.po-form-print.poHeader', compact('poData')),
                'footer-html' => view('view-purchase-order.po-form-print.poFooter', compact('poData')),
                'header-spacing' => 0,
                'footer-spacing' => 0,
            ]);

return $pdf->stream('');

I've tried adjusting the css of content and make it relative but it doesn't work.
